# Have a new element appear in the middle of a SVG.js animation timeline

Tags: svg.js

I have a SVG.js animation timeline and want some text to appear 5 seconds in. I thought maybe I could do:

```
var popup = draw.text('Here is my text').attr({x:250, y:225 }).hide();
popup.animate(0, 5000).show();
```

The hide() works, but show() isn't an animation method.

Comment: Try the css method to remove display prop `css('display', null)`

Answer (score 0):

with attr() try setting the initial opacity: 0  and changing it to opacity: 1

```
popup.animate(0, 5000).attr({ opacity: 1 });
```

I don't think either hide or show are library methods